# More intuitive formatting for a SQL insert formed with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I wish to know how to make this code (and similar) more intuitive:

```
<?php 
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `depositors` (`name`, `surname`, `mobile`, `telephone`, `email`';
    $query = $this->_params['state'] === 'active' ? $query : $query.', `state`';
    $query = !empty($this->_params['hours']) ? $query.', `hours no.`' :  $query;
    $query = $query.') ';
    $query = $query."VALUES ('".$this->_params['name']."', '".$this->_params['surname']."', '".$this->_params['mobile']."', '".$this->_params['telephone']."', '".$this->_params['email']."'";
    $query = $this->_params['state'] === 'active' ? $query : $query.", '".$this->_params['state']."'";
    $query = !empty($this->_params['hours']) ? $query.', '.$this->_params['hours'] :  $query;
    $query = $query.')'; 
?>
```

I am **not** searching for an answer like

> Substitute "x ? y : z" with "if (x) {y} else {z}"

I am searching for a more elegant way.

I am aware of SQL injection, but at this point, there are no controls **by design**.  I also know about PDO (and I'm actually using it, but not there).

Comment: Please take a look at our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). A question is on topic only if "I want feedback about any and all aspects of the code". There is little sense to arguing with people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code can be drastically simplified, and there are significant bugs too.

First, the bugs. SQLInjection is a serious bug because it allows a malicious attacker to compromise your system. Vogel612 has already emphatically pointed that out. On the other hand, SQLInjection is simply a way to exploit a bug in your code in an intentionally malicious way... The bug has to be there first... and, in this case, your bug is that you do not 'sanitize' or 'escape' the values you concatenate in to the String query. Now, why is that bad? Well, I work with a person who's name is *`O'Connor`*. You cannot save that name using your system. It fails to execute. A malicious person could use that fact to craft a name which does more damage than just fail.....

A second item of interest, is that you are not running a query, you are performing an insert. Calling it 'query' is not helpful.

Finally, when you do not mention a column as part of an insert statement, it gets the value null. So, you are inserting null values in to the `hours no.` and `active` columns when the params are not set right. There is no need for the conditional columns if you can just insert null values explicitly.

Now, all of these issues can be easily solved using parametrized statements. Vogel612 has already strongly recommended them, to solve the injection, but they will also solve the complexity of the code....

Consider a PDO solution:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `depositors` (`name`, `surname`, `mobile`, `telephone`, `email`, `state`, `hours no.`) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (':name, :surname, :mobile, :telephone, :email, :state, :hours)";

$statement = $conn.prepare($sql);

$statement.execute(array(
     ':name'=>$this->_params['name'],
     ':surname'=>$this->_params['surname'],
     ':mobile'=>$this->_params['mobile'],
     ':telephone'=>$this->_params['telephone'],
     ':email'=>$this->_params['email'],
     ':state'=>$this->_params['state'] === 'active' ? 'active' : null,
     ':hours'=>$this->_params['hours'] ? $this->_params['hours'] : null));
```

Comment: 1: first of all, there is no control for SQL injections **by design**.

Comment: 2: why you are so sure that _$this->_params_ contains user input? is not right, this array contains data already processed by the system somewhere else. so i can insert _O'Connor_ etc.

Comment: 3: yes, you are right, i need to call it _insert_, not _query_.

Comment: 4:if hours field contain a default value, your _null_ substitutes the default value or not?

Comment: @Zhigalin `name`, `email`, etc sure **sound** like user supplied data. And user supplied data is still user supplied even if it was processed somewhere else. If you state something like `no defending against sql injections **by design**`, you should really expand on that, otherwise answers **will** comment on this.

Comment: @Zhigalin - I guess you are right, feel free to ignore or downvote my answer. On the other hand, if you do not supply all the relevant information required to make a meaningful review to your code, then obviously your question is poorly asked.

Comment: "**you do not supply all the relevant information**" for example?

Comment: why i must downvote/ignore your answer?

Comment: You don't have to (and I never said you have to, I said feel free to), but you have spent a number of comments telling me why all the things I suggest are either meaningless or wrong. As for comments in general, there are too many comments on this answer already. I should start a chat room for this question.

Comment: your answer is right, except for comments number 1 and 2, and i need a clarification about number 4.

Comment: Well, Default values at the database level will be ignored if you specify a null value explicitly, depending on the database, it seems. You can either go back to your original code, or you can include the default code in your application (in addition to the database?). Your call. Frankly, though, this is the least of your problems, and your insistence on not using prepared statements is 99% of my suggestion, so the rest is just fluff. There is no point in me debating the small details if it depends on a major item you disagree with.

Comment: @rolfl it is possible to use the [default database value with PDO](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64078/49695) without hardcoding it into the application itself.

Answer (score 5):

## SECURITY ALERT!!

[You are vulnerable to SQL-Injections.](http://bobby-tables.com/) You should never concat user-input into your query!

Instead you should use either [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) database wrappers, that allow parameterized queries.

Keep in mind, if you do these wrong, you can still break your own neck...

### Nitpicks

- Even though you mention it. Your inlined ternary statements are concealing the meaning of the code and make it hard to read... Get rid of them.
- You can shorthand `$query = $query.'whatever'` to `$query .= 'whatever'`

Comment: 1: question updated.
2: question updated.
3: thanks.

Comment: THIS IS NOT ABOUT INPUT VALIDATION! You need to know the difference between input validation and SQL-Injections. Please read up on why SQL-Injections can break your system!

Comment: For me input validaton includes a sql check.

Answer (score 5):

I would use prepared statements as [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64072/49695) suggested.
It's easier to read, and it's more secure (not preventing SQL injection at the point of inserting data into the database seems like very bad design: it's easy to forget, and hard to catch if forgotten (as it happens somewhere else) and it makes it impossible to use prepared statements, so you are relying on escaping the input instead of separating SQL syntax from data).

But if you insist on your solution, it can be improved upon:

- be consistent with single and double quotes. It makes it really hard to see what is a string and what not if you mix them up like you are doing right now.
- use spaces around `.`
- use `$query .=` instead of `$query = $query.`
- hardcode `active` string on insert after check if it is `active`.
- add single quotes around `$this->_params['hours']` on insert (it's easy to overlook these, which is one of the reasons prepared statements are better than this approach).

With these changes, your code might look like this:

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO `depositors` (`name`, `surname`, `mobile`, `telephone`, `email`";
$query .= ($this->_params['state'] === "active") ? ", `state`" : "";
$query .= !empty($hours) ? ", `hours no.`" : "";
$query .= ") ";

$query .= "VALUES ('" . $this->_params['name'] . "', '" . $this->_params['surname'] . "', '" . $this->_params['mobile'] . "', '" . $this->_params['telephone'] . "', '" . $this->_params['email'] . "'";
$query .= ($this->_params['state'] === "active") ? ", 'active'" : "";
$query .= !empty($this->_params['hours']) ? ", '" . $this->_params['hours'] . "'": "";
$query .= ")";
```

And if you get rid of the ternary operator it could look like this:

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO `depositors` (`name`, `surname`, `mobile`, `telephone`, `email`";
if ($this->_params['state'] === 'active')   $query .= ", `state`";
if (!empty($this->_params['hours']))        $query .= ", `hours no.`";
                                            $query .= ") ";

$query .= "VALUES ('" . $this->_params['name'] . "', '" . $this->_params['surname'] . "', '" . $this->_params['mobile'] . "', '" . $this->_params['telephone'] . "', '" . $this->_params['email'] . "'";
if ($this->_params['state'] === 'active')   $query .= ", 'active'";
if (!empty($this->_params['hours']))        $query .= ", '" . $this->_params['hours'] . "'";
                                            $query .= ")";
```

or differently formated:

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO `depositors` (`name`, `surname`, `mobile`, `telephone`, `email`";
if ($this->_params['state'] === 'active') {
    $query .= ", `state`";
}
if (!empty($this->_params['hours'])) {      
    $query .= ", `hours no.`";
}
$query .= ") ";

$query .= "VALUES ('" . $this->_params['name'] . "', '" . $this->_params['surname'] . "', '" . $this->_params['mobile'] . "', '" . $this->_params['telephone'] . "', '" . $this->_params['email'] . "'";
if ($this->_params['state'] === 'active') {
    $query .= ", 'active'";
}
if (!empty($this->_params['hours'])) {
    $query .= ", '" . $this->_params['hours'] . "'";
}
$query .= ")";
```

I think that it is more readable with `if` instead of the ternary operator, but that's just a personal preference.

As for the default problem with [@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/64072/49695)s answer, [you can use `IFNULL(:state, DEFAULT(state))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130583/pdo-prepared-statement-insert-default-when-the-variable-in-bindparam-is-null) (or check out this post for more solutions on how to [insert the default database value using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464535/preparing-a-mysql-insert-update-statement-with-default-values)):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `depositors` (`name`, `surname`, `mobile`, `telephone`, `email`, `state`, `hours no.`) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (':name, :surname, :mobile, :telephone, :email, IFNULL(:state, DEFAULT(state)), IFNULL(:hours, DEFAULT(hours)))";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);    
$statement->execute(array(
     ':name'        => $this->_params['name'],
     ':surname'     => $this->_params['surname'],
     ':mobile'      => $this->_params['mobile'],
     ':telephone'   => $this->_params['telephone'],
     ':email'       => $this->_params['email'],
     ':state'       => $this->_params['state'] === 'active' ? 'active' : null,
     ':hours'       => $this->_params['hours'] ? $this->_params['hours'] : null));
```

Comment: Nice, and oversupplying the parameters and not using them if null, is an interesting approach.